Do I need to download GCC compiler in order to run unity code?
I am trying to create a racing unity game. I have gotten the assets set up and everything, but I would like to know if I need to download a gcc compiler to code in Unity. If so, which type of gcc is recommended. Thank you.

You might use it, but assuming you're a complete beginner it's probable that you'll only need to write C# scripts, for this you need .NET build tools, gcc is not needed

probably need some .NET SDK .. simply install visual studio along with Unity .. it should install everything required

You don't need anything, the Unity Editor installs everything you need, including the C# compiler (you don't need a .NET SDK). If you are meaning to work with the C++ code of Unity (which is only accessible if you've paid quite a lot of money), you should have enough instructions on how to build that part and should not need to come here.

gcc would likely only be needed if you wanted to compile yourself up some DLLs

You don't need an additional C# compiler with Unity. It already has a C# compiler for itself. Just edit the code and save it, it will automatically be compiled
